# kafka connect creates no workers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

When creating a connector via either a put/push request using the following config

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
    "transforms.convert_scns.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast$Value",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": "5",
    "transforms": "unwrap,convertTS,convert_scns,reroute",
    "transforms.reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
    "transforms.convertTS.format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
    "transforms.convertTS.target.type": "Timestamp",
    "schema.history.internal.store.only.captured.tables.ddl": "true",
    "topic.prefix": "topic_name",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "double",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "2",
    "transforms.convertTS.field": "__source_ts_ms",
    "transforms.reroute.topic.regex": "topic_name\\.([^.]+)\\.table_name",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "transforms.convertTS.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "database.user": "",
    "database.dbname": "",
    "transforms.reroute.topic.replacement": "topic_name",
    "time.precision.mode": "connect",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "ip:9092,ip:9092,ip:9092",
    "database.port": "",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://ip:8085",
    "database.hostname": "",
    "database.password": "",
    "name": "name",
    "numeric.mapping": "best_fit",
    "transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "op,source.ts_ms,source.schema,source.scn,source.commit_scn,source.db",
    "table.include.list": "table_name",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://ip:8085",
    "snapshot.mode": "initial",
    "transforms.convert_scns.spec": "__source_commit_scn:int64,__source_scn:int64,__deleted:boolean"
}
```

The connector is created, this can be seen via kafka-ui as well as in the logs

```
Instantiated connector test_connector with version 2.1.3.Final of type class io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:315)
[2023-04-17 17:37:10,376] INFO [test_connector|worker] Finished creating connector test_connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:336)
[2023-04-17 17:37:10,377] DEBUG [test_connector|worker] WorkerConnector{id=test_connector} Initializing connector test_connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:166)
[2023-04-17 17:37:10,377] DEBUG [test_connector|worker] WorkerConnector{id=test_connector} Transition connector to STARTED (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:355)
```

Nothing else then happens until the API returns a 500 and in the logs a timeout can be see before this. No worker is created for the task, or any topics. restarting the connector creates a task and then the relevant topics. What is going wrong for the connector to need restarting before working. This only happens under the following conditions

- JSONConverter -> worked fine
- JSONConverter with schema registry -> worked fine
- AvroConverter with schema registry -> hung and required a restart of the connector

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Clearly the issue is the AvroConverter config... JSONConverter doesn't need a Registry. 1) Is your Registry actually running? 2) Schema Registry defaults to run on port 8081. Why change this? 3) You should be seeing logs with the Registry client failure / timeouts before Connect worker API throws 500

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer to answer your questions. yes the schema registry is running. on a refresh of the connector once posted it creates the schema. the port wouldnt make a difference as we can see it connect on the refresh but not on the initial load. Finally there is nothing in the logs ( set to trace) for a schema registry error

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the JVM at all? Any memory/io spikes causing it to stall?

Comment: the memory and cpu usage when posting a connector are low. cpu doesn't go above 5% and heap size seems to always be around 50% used. so nothing seems weird there. we've tried moving the schema register to the same box and pointing to local host and that didnt change anything either

Comment: I assume you're using latest version of Kafka Connect and Debezium? Does your database have any firewall that's blocking requests? You've double checked all the user/server/password values are correct (also, don't store these in plaintext in Connector config, but that's a separate issue)

Comment: in the logs i can see that the connector tests the connection to the DB using the config passed before finalizing the creation of the connector

Comment: also both connect and debizium are the latest versions

Comment: Don't really have any suggestions here. There are [other ways](https://debezium.io/community/) to get community support for Debezium.